# Magento - Lightbox age verification script - two elements are not being hidden by lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magento, lightbox

There are two div elements that are not being covered by the lightbox generated by my age verification script, the search box and the facebook slideout (which also seems to have stopped functioning, but that's another question).  I've asked for help from the theme developer, but the response was that they don't support theme modifications.

You can see the issue live at http://www.vaporspaceabq.com.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the searchbox and the facebook thing have a z-index over 9000(lol^^) change the z-index of the overlay to something higher than both of the visible elements. The z-index of the facebook-widget is 99998 so a z-index of 99999 on the overlay should fix this.

here is some css:

```
div#verify { z-index: 100000; }
div.lb_overlay.js_lb_overlay{ z-index: 99999; }
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to change the index a little differently (adding zIndex:100000 to the lightbox_me instantiation) but this was definitely the problem.

Comment: yhea my bad inline css has a higher priority than your included css, another option would have been to override the inline with !important like that: `div#verify { z-index: 100000 !important; }`